# Total number of state entries

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, synchronization, fast-sync

I am syncing my ethereum blockchain using the default syncmode. I want to know **how many total state entries are there** because currently the highest block is 6544578 and the number of pulled states i.e. 65802151 is higher than the highest block number.

Comment: have patience , downloading state entries is the most time consuming process of syncing, it takes much more than downloading block headers.

Comment: But still any rough any idea on the total number?

Comment: I don't know , but not 66 million, maybe 300 million or so ....

Comment: Oh! Guess it'll take 2 3 days more